# Object function is passed as argument, how access parent object in that function?

Tags: javascript, object, this

I have the following situation:

```
function dog()
{
    this.name = 'Lumpy';
    this.getName = function() {
        return this.name;
    }
}

function show_dog_name(dogname)
{
    alert(dogname());
}

bigdog = new dog();
show_dog_name(bigdog.getName);
```

"this" not refers to "dog" object so how get parent object in passed function.

Comment: Your class is called `dog` in one place and `Dog` in another.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
var that = this;
this.getName = function() { return that.name; };
```

Comment: Thanks, know I know about jsFiddle's existence ;-)

Answer (score 1):

You can create `dog` like this:

```
function dog()
{
    var name = 'Lumpy';
    this.getName = function() {
        return name;
    }
}
```

This create a closure that allow you `getName` to always be able to access `name`.
If you want the dog  name to be 'public' to your object, you can use:

```
var name = 'Lumpy';
this.name = name;
```

Another solution consist to make the 'right' `this` object always available for your `getName` function:

```
var dogObj = this;
this.name = 'Lumpy';
this.getName = function() {
  return dogObj.name;
}
```

Comment: Make it `var name`, you don't really want it to be global, do you? ;-)

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
function dog(){
    this.name = 'Lumpy';
    var obj=this;
    this.getName = function() {
        return obj.name;
    }
}

function show_dog_name(dogname){
    alert(dogname());
}

bigdog = new dog();
show_dog_name(bigdog.getName);
```